# Swap content between screens

Tags: ubuntu, opensuse, gnu-screen, desktop-shortcuts

I'm using Opensuse 15. I use two monitors a small one on the left and big one in front of me.

Sometimes I would like  to change all the programs from my left screen to the other one and vice-versa by pressing a shortcut instead of dragging windows with the mouse.

EX: I have mozilla in the central screen and terminal in the other one. Now i want to use terminal but keep mozilla in the small screen.

There is a way to do that easily with a shortcut? Can it be done in Ubuntu as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and then the arrow keys to position your window. It's cumbersome but works. I don't know of any quick short cut to shift windows across workspaces.

You can shift windows *between* workspaces with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> and then use the arrows to navigate your configured workspaces.

Comment: That didn't work to me. 
I have added a new keybind in opensuse to switch between desktops.
Not exactly what i wanted but good enough.